# LED recessed fixture is consistently malfunctioning in a specific location

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

My parents just installed LED recessed lighting kits (integrated LED fixtures containing the diode and driver circuitry), and they are having a very strange problem.

One toggle switch controls about 6 recessed lights. When switching the lights on, 5 of them work just fine, but one of them only flickers. When turning the switch off, the flickering light suddenly gives a burst of very bright light.

My initial assumption was that the flickering bulb was defective. However, they swapped out the entire recessed kit for a new one, and the exact same behavior is occurring. Is there something else (some type of wiring issue?) that would be a likely culprit?

UPDATE: a similar effect is actually happening on a second circuit of identical fixtures. According to the installer, the malfunctioning LEDs are in both cases the last ones on the circuit. This seems like an important clue...

Video of the phenomenon [here](https://streamable.com/7whms).

Thanks!

Comment: I'd replace the misbehaving one with a halogen. If the halogen also blinks and flickers, then that can't be an electronics problem because it has no electronics, so it would point towards a bad contact, or bad wiring.

Comment: there probably something funny in the wire between the last correctly working lamp and the misbehaving one. try replacing that wire temporarily with a surface wire.

Comment: Are there any electronics (transformers, diodes, capacitors, smart switches, etc.) connected to this circuit? I've seen led lights behind a miswired smart switch flash and flicker similar to this, just not the bright flash when they're turned off.